# how to click elements inside popupwindow with arrayadapter using espresso

Tags: autocomplete, android-arrayadapter, android-espresso

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7S72.png)

when user enter starting two alphabets a window pop up,
Need to Click on the Third Element with unique Only Content Description that is just the name  And also some define difrrence betwen content.description and content.text in espresso and the data comes from arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to test search suggestions.
You can try this code,

```
onView(withText("Sarah Friedrich"))
            .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(rule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```